# Is there an application to link words between several documents?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm looking for a software in which I could insert a batch of text documents and then link words inside them.

For example: I have doc1, doc2, doc3. doc1 is about animals, doc2 is about dogs, doc3 is about blind people. I'd like an application in which I could manually link the word "dog" between the 3 documents.

Edit: The purpose is to visualize the links (e.g. colored lines) to expose patterns between the documents. For example, having a number of documents side-by-side with colored lines linking specific words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may not be an existing program that will do exactly what you want. But what you are describing is a kind of "content analysis", similar to what many researchers do with various kinds of qualitative data. Here are two lists of software packages meant to help with that sort of task.

http://onlineqda.hud.ac.uk/Step_by_step_software/index.php

http://textanalysis.info/pages/resources/overviews.php

You may also consider looking for tools that would help you with the process in separate steps. For instance, WFCA (http://www.hermetic.ch/wfca/wfca.htm) can give you counts of appearances of words across the documents, but it won't show them to you side by side in context.

If you are able to save the files as plain text instead of Word, it may increase your options. I can imagine developing a macro or script in emacs text editor (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) that would do something like what you want.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you go about to do this with emacs?

Comment: To really do it well, you would have to write an elisp script. There are folks on Stackoverflow who would definitely know enough to accomplish this but it might be a lot of work. But if you can generate a list of keywords with something like WFCA, it wouldn't be hard to record some macros that allow you to quickly search several files side by side for those keywords one at a time.

Comment: @NunoCastro Re-reading this question I see that you are hoping for colored lines between the words in the docs... that would not by possible in emacs. What I was thinking was color coding the matching words.

Comment: Let us know if you find a good solution... I would find this useful. In the meantime I am trying to figure out if I can hack something together in Python.

Comment: Sure. I still haven't found a concrete solution but during my searches I've found a very useful program for finding conceptual\semantic patterns in documents: [AutoMap](http://www.casos.cs.cmu.edu/projects/automap/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can can insert the hyperlink to documents

check screen short, follow the detailed steps here

http://www.hartnell.edu/library/word_web_design/links.htm

[image]

There is another way around but that's complex

creating Master Document word file

A master document is a Word file that contains links to a set of other, separate Word files, called subdocuments. The content of the subdocuments is not inserted into the master document. The master document only contains links to the subdocuments. This allows you to edit the subdocuments separately. Any changes made to subdocuments are incorporated into the master document automatically. If there are multiple people working on a single document, a master document allows you to send different parts of the document to different people to work on.

check details here

http://www.howtogeek.com/73960/create-a-master-document-in-word-2010-from-multiple-documents/

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I guess I forgot to specify a little further. I'm looking for visual links (e.g. colored lines) not the usual computer links. I added a brief comment to the question so that the purpose of the question is more understandable.